# 2-dimesional array from two 1-dimensional arrays

Tags: vbscript

For example:

```
a1 = Split("item1 item2 item3")
a2 = Split("value1 value2 value3")
```

Now I want to create 2-dimensional array named `a` (2x3 or in vbscript syntax `array(1,2)`)

Is there a way to create this 2-dimensional array without traversing former mentioned arrays element by element?

As a matter of fact I don't even want to create 1-dimensional arrays, but I want to use Split() function and immediately assign each split in adequate 2-dimensional array row, but I can't find any reference how it could be possible. All examples I see are assigning each element separately, like:

```
Dim a(1,2)
a(0)(0) = "item1"
a(0)(1) = "item2"
...
```

while I would like something like:

```
Dim a(1,2)
a(0) = Split("item1 item2 item3")
a(1) = Split("value1 value2 value3")
```

or anything similar without assigning every element separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it [here](http://camie.dyndns.org/technical/vbscript-arrays/). It is easy as:

```
a = Array(Split("item1 item2 item3"), Split("value1 value2 value3"))
```